# Getting URL from WinJS.xhr Response

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, windows-store-apps, winjs

Suppose I have a loop in which I call `WinJS.xhr()` on multiple addresses.  In the response handler, is there a way to determine the address from which the response is being handled?  Either by discerning it from the XmlHttpRequest object that `xhr()` passes to the handler or by passing something else in manually?

I've been looking through [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms535874.aspx) as well as examining the response in the debugger but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that information is in the response, but it doesn't need to be. Every xhr call has its own Promise that is returned for that specific call. I like to do it this way...

```
//start with an array of some kind
var urls = [
    "http://something.com/1",
    "http://something.com/2",
    "http://something.com/3",
];

//map the array to a list of calls adding your url in so you have it
var results = urls.map(function(u) {
    return {url:u, response:WinJS.xhr({url:u})};
}
```

And then you can loop the results array and you have the url. You might want to wrap that in another promise so the whole thing is asynchronous.

```
function xhrCallsAsync() {

    //start with an array of some kind
    var urls = [
        "http://something.com/1",
        "http://something.com/2",
        "http://something.com/3",
    ];

    //map the array to a list of calls adding your url in so you have it
    var results = urls.map(function(u) {
        return {url:u, response:WinJS.xhr({url:u})};
    }

    //return a Promise that completes when all of the Promises are complete
    return WinJS.Promise.join(results);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The other tweak i've used here is to have the first promise in the chain be a wrapper, and return the result as a rich object funneled through a .join. e.g. (silly formatting, sorry): WinJS.Promise.join({ url: yourSourceUrl, xhr: WinJS.xhr({url: yourSourceUrl }), }).then(function(result) { // you get result.url, and result.xhr as the completed results });

Comment: Awesome suggestion.  What I ended up doing was to use `u` directly in the `.done()` on `.xhr()` within the call to `map()`.  (So no additional loop.)  Works like a charm!

Comment: @Jeremy Foster This didn't work for me. When I call 'xhrCallsAsync().done(function(results){});' the results object has array containing url and xhr. So it didn't make any ajax call yet? Do I need to loop over results and then for each we'll call result.xhr.done() to get actual response?